# Altair chart out of container while container_width set true

Tags: streamlit, altair, vega-lite

#### Summary

Problem is my chart has many columns, is there a way my chart's width is set to his container because it's out of his container now.

#### Steps to reproduce

**Code snippet:**

```
from vega_datasets import data
source = data.barley()

b = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year:O', title=None),
    y='yield:Q',
    color='variety:N',
    column=alt.Column('site:N', title=None,
                      header=alt.Header(labelColor='blue'))
)
st.altair_chart(b, use_container_width=True)
```

**Expected behavior:**

Chart should be inside the container, no scrolling needed.

#### Additional information

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make the graph appear fully on screen without any scrollbar. Use `st.columns` and put the graph inside the first column (`columns[0]`).

```py
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st
from vega_datasets import data

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

source = data.barley()

b = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year:O', title=None),
    y='yield:Q',
    color='variety:N',
    column=alt.Column('site:N', title=None,
                      header=alt.Header(labelColor='blue'))
)

cols = st.columns([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
with cols[0]:
    st.altair_chart(b, use_container_width=True)

st.header("Some title")
st.markdown("Some text")
```

It gives:

[image: The graph holds in full screen.]

---

I also added `st.set_page_config` to set `layout="wide"` in order to have more place on the screen to display the graph, but it works without it. Also, if need be, just add or remove some columns.

---

Note: When resizing the screen, this solution keeps the graph fully on the screen:

[image: The browser size is reduced to less than 50% of the width of the former picture but the graph is still fully on screen, matching the width!]

Comment: This indeed does work, the problem for me is, this was an example used to demo my problem. I have many columns like 15 but I found out there is no point stretching because they get very close to each other so I split them in rows, each row containing 5 rows. Did this with facet. Appreciate the work tho!